# php pdo sql return if rows exist

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In PHP PDO trying to use `SELECT COUNT(*) SQL` to see if primary key exists (so then can update rather than insert),

When I call the function `sqlCall; fetchColumn()` returns 0 or 1 depending on if it exists or not, however when it is returned it always returns false?

How do I get it to return if row exists or not?

Thanks for help!!

```
 function sqlCall($primary) {

            $sql = $handler->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  WHERE ". strtolower($primary)."=:".$primary);

            $sSqlParams = array(':'.$primary => $primary);

            $sql->execute($sSqlParams);


            if($sql->fetchColumn()==1){
                return 1;

            } else {
                return 0;
            }
            break;
}




try {
                $rows = sqlCall($primary);

                if($rows=True){
                    //UPDATE SQL
                } else {
                    //INSERT SQL
                }
}
catch(PDOException $er) {

                    die();
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here? `WHERE ". strtolower($primary)."=:".$primary` is your  $primary the same as your column name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going about this wrong way - there is MySQL construct which allows you to do this without any need for workarounds. If you would like to update record if exists and if not insert it than use: [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

It goes like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (primary_key, field_to_update) VALUES(primary_key_value, value_to_update) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field_to_update = value_to_update
```

Whenever your primar_key will be already in database the record will be updated and if primary_key does not exists than new record will be created.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this later on :)